# Css : text-transform: none not working

Tags: html, css

i dont understand why  doesn't work text-transform : none on my div
any idea ?

**HTML**

```
  <html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>


    <h3>
      Fromage
      <div class="count">
      5
      </div>
    </h3>
</body>

</html>
```

**style**

```
  h3{
  font-family: krinkes_decor;
      text-transform: none;
}

.count{
      text-transform: none;

}

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'krinkes_decor';
        src: url('krinkesdecorpersonal-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),url('/C:\Users\achraf\Desktop\testeur\krinkesdecorpersonal-webfont.ttf');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }
```

Comment: You have text-transform set to none, it literally means "do none transformations to text" so it working exactly as it should. You need rephrase your question and explain what is expected behaviour

Comment: change the `font-family` if you don't want it be displayed with the one you're using in your `h3`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp
The value none for `text-decoration` as quoted "No capitalization. The text renders as it is. This is default" that means it sets it to default and changes nothing.